# Error while trying to loop through Column Values in VB.NET DataList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, foreach

I am trying to loop through a column in my VB.NET datalist and it is returning this error in debug.

my code:

```
        For Each dlitem In DataList1.Items
        Dim tb1 = CType(dlitem.FindControl("Supplier"), TextBox)
    Next
```

my error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   App_Web_kohpneqb.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' to type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Comment: What is `Supplier` in your mark-up? Looks like `HiddenField`, error message is self explanatory.

Comment: Try this:  Dim tb1 = CType(dlitem.FindControl("Supplier"), HiddenField)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending my comment, the exception message looks self explanatory. In your DataList control `Supplier` is defined as HiddenField but you are trying to cast it as `Textbox` control. Cast it to HiddenField instead:-

```
Dim tb1 As HiddenField = CType(dlitem.FindControl("Supplier"), HiddenField)
```